# What is the difference between the two method in persian datepicke

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have the following javascript code snippet in my laravel project:

```
$('#deadline').change(function() {
    const dval =parseInt($('#deadline').val());
    const startdate=document.getElementById("startdate").value;
    const startdateToEnglish= startdate.toEnglishDigit();
    console.log("startdate: "+startdate+"  interval: "+dval);
    var inputF = document.getElementById("enddate"); 
    edate=new persianDate().format();
    edate1=new persianDate([startdateToEnglish]).add('days', dval).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
    console.log("startdateToEnglish: "+startdateToEnglish);
    edate2=new persianDate([1402,08,01]).add('days', dval).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
    inputF.value = edate; 

   console.log("edate1:  "+edate1+"     edate2:   "+edate2 );
```

The outputs in the console are as follows:

```
startdate: ۱۴۰۲,۰۸,۱  interval: 1
startdateToEnglish: 1402,08,01
edate1:  NaN/NaN/NaN     edate2:   ۱۴۰۲/۰۸/۰۲
```

Both terms edate1 and edate2 are the same ,why value of edate1 is NaN/NaN/NaN , And what is the solution to get the output just like the edate2?

Comment: I _suppose_ the `startdateToEnglish` is a string `1402,08,01` while `[1402,08,01]` is an array of 3 integers. What does `.toEnglishDigit()` do/return?

Comment: convert persian numbers in string to english number

Comment: Does it return anything, or does it give an error in your console? `toEnglishDigit()` isn't a native function, and `startDate` is a string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

probably you have to split `startdateToEnglish`  by comma and assign to an array.

```
const startdateToEngArray = startdateToEnglish.split(',').map(Number);
edate1 = new persianDate(startdateToEngArray).add('days', dval).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
```

give it a try.